# How to send attachment and set email priority using javascript REST API in SharePoint Hosted App?

Tags: javascript, rest, sharepoint

I have a requirement where in i need to send email with priority set and with attachment. Currently I am using "/_api/SP.Utilities.Utility.SendEmail" REST API to send email; but not sure how to set email priority and attachment to email using REST. 
Here is my code:

```
var urlTemplate = SPAppWebUrl + "/_api/SP.Utilities.Utility.SendEmail";
    $.ajax({
        contentType: 'application/json',
        url: urlTemplate,
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify({
            'properties': {
                '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.Utilities.EmailProperties' },
                'From': from,
                'To': { 'results': [to] },
                'Body': emailBody,
                'Subject': subject
            }
        }
      ),
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
        },
        success: function (data) {
            //console.log('success')
            alert('email send successfull..');
        },
        error: function (err) {
            //console.log(JSON.stringify(err));
            alert(JSON.stringify(err));
        }
    });
```

Any help or other approach/pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, "SP.Utilities.EmailProperties" (SP.js) object has the following properties available for use in your script: 
*From, To, CC, BCC, Subject, Body and AdditionalHeaders*

For Attachments, you will have to try a server-side approach or workflow.
You can refer to the MSDN link [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj246895.aspx).

There is a SP 2010 workflow activity solution in codeplex which you can use for sending email with attachments. You can refer to http://sharepointstuff.codeplex.com/